# What do you like about me?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, word-usage

so umm.. let's say that you're asking your partner on what he think about yourself. Somethings like "What do you like about me?" 
Does this sentence sounds right?:
「私について何が好きですか?」

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to ask that would be...

> 私のどこが好き？♡

Comment: ↑ This sounds pretty feminine though... 男の人はなんて言うでしょうかね？ 「俺のどこが好き？」とか？

Comment: If I am expecting an answer like 「特にはない。」, is that a suitable question? I'm actually creating script.. hehe

Comment: @T49 Then how about...「私（なんか）のどこがいいの？」/「俺（なんか）のどこがいいんだ？」(What do you see in me?)

Comment: なるほど。Is it okay if I left out（なんか）in the sentence? And thank you for correcting me. It should be 「特にない。」instead of 「特にはない。」, right? haha

Comment: @T49 I think you can leave out なんか, but it might be more natural (and a bit more emphatic) to say it 「私なんかのどこがいいの？/俺なんかのどこがいいんだ？」/「（いったい）私（なんか）のどこがいいって言うの？/（いったい）俺（なんか）のどこがいいってんだ？」 if you imply 「いいところなんか、ないでしょう？」... 「特にはない」 is not incorrect but I think 「特にない。」/「別にない。」 are a bit more natural and common.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up my confusion. I learnt a lot today.